# If Y is orthogonal, does it follow that $Y^{-1}XY$ is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with what my professor has written in my notes, because he hasn't proven this anywhere. In part of a longer proof, this comes up:

"Since *Y* is an orthogonal matrix, so is $Y^{-1}XY$. It follows that  $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c&d \end{bmatrix}$ is an orthogonal matrix, having determinant 1, so it is a rotation in the plane *W*"

$$Y^{-1}XY=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a & b \\ 0 & c & d \end{pmatrix}$$

Is it true in general that if *Y* is orthogonal, $Y^{-1}XY$ is orthogonal?

This is part of a proof of this theorem: If *X* is a *3x3* orthogonal matrix with det *X* = 1, then *X* is given by rotation around some line *L* through the origin about some angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question in the title is obviously false by taking $X=0$, say.  But note that here $X$ is also orthogonal, and the product of any two or more orthogonal matrices is orthogonal (you should try proving this, it's quite simple).  Since both $Y$ and $Y^{-1}$ are orthogonal, it should be clear that so is $Y^{-1}XY$.

Comment: I forgot that X was orthogonal. Is there any way I can delete this question? It makes me look dumb haha

Comment: @MarkT I wouldn't know how, but I'm sure I've seen other questions voluntarily retracted.